# URL being truncated using UIWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Tags: ios

I'm loading a local web page and intercepting web clicks using:

> - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
>     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

However if there is something like this in the html:

> href="http://www.zagat.com/Verticals/PropertyDetails.aspx?VID=8&R=36121">

(I can't past XML properly on this site without it not being displayed properly, but its not the XML to look at but the href url)

Then within shouldStartLoadWithRequest if I have this:

> NSString *scheme = [[request URL] scheme]; NSString *host = [[request
>   URL] host];

scheme is "http" and host is "www.zagat.com".

Is there a way I can extract the full string of "www.zagat.com/Verticals/PropertyDetails.aspx?VID=8&R=36121" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSString * fullURL = [[request URL] absoluteString];`